# When enter pressed

Tags: javascript

I have a textarea which must be limited to 100 characters, and want each line break to match 10 characters.

I did something like:

```js
let counter = 0;

$('textarea').keypress(function(e) {
    var tval = $('textarea').val(),
        tlength = tval.length,
        set = 10,
        remain = parseInt(set - tlength);

    if (e.which === 13) {
        counter++;
    } else {
        counter = 0;
    }
    if (counter > 1) {
        alert('new line')
    }

    $('p').text(remain);
    if (remain <= 0 && e.which !== 0 && e.charCode !== 0) {
        $('textarea').val((tval).substring(0, tlength - 1))
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
<p></p>
```

But I dont know how to add 10 characters when I press twice "enter". now if I press twice the "enter" button I will use 2 characters but I want to use 10.

EDIT:
exemple :

```
hello //5 characters
      //empty line break 10 characters
world //5 characters
```

for exemple, between "hello" and "world" i have 1 new line, and i want these 1 new line use 10 charaters, so in this exemple i used 20 characters ( 5 for hello + 10 for the line break and 5 for world )

Comment: I'll throw a wrinkle into your plans.  You're currently only handling `keypress`.  I can paste text into a textarea with my mouse, that would never invoke the keypress event

Comment: Do yo want add 10 to counter every new line or if there is an empty line?

Comment: i edited my request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly this should works.

This code get the text into `textarea` splitted by `\n`.

So, the total number of characters (without count the break line itself) is:

- Get total number of characters
- Split by new line
- Get number of lines
- Get empty lines

Total count is: Number of characters in text area + number of empty lines * 10 - new line character.

Also, the function is called when `change`, `keyup` or `paste` to avoid problems.

```js
let counter = 0;

$('textarea').on('change keyup paste',function(e) {
    
    var text = $("textarea").val();
    var count = text.length;
    var nLine = text.split(/\n/)
    var breakLines = nLine.filter(x => x === "").length
    counter = count + (breakLines*10) - (nLine.length -1)
    console.log("counter = ",counter)
    
    //Do whatever you want

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
<p></p>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. it lil bit what i need. for exemple i need to add 10 characters after a full line break (not just a new line, like in my exemple) so in your code i did "split(/\n\n/)". and that work but exemple when i write "hello" and make line break i have 16 (its good) but if i write a new word i get "7" and its not good

Comment: If the new line is not empty the code not count 10. This is what I've understood. That's why in the first new line the code count +10 but if you write in this line, then not add 10 to the total count (because the line is not empty)

Comment: yeah a emtpy new line is 10 characters it good. sorry but i edited my request again to see what i wanted to say :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand because "hello + empty line + hello" = 20 characters is exactly what my code does.

Comment: ohh ok sorry, I had seen badly, thank you so much

Comment: A last thing, how to stop writing in the text area if the numbers of characters is >= of the maxlength of the text area ?